# S3 bucket mounted on Ec2 directory. It is not showing any content

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, putty

We have mounted an S3 bucket onto a folder in Ec2. The total size on S3 is 7gb. The folder on ec2 has synched and is showing two folders but is not showing any other folders or subfolders in the bucket

The command we have used is

`sudo s3fs bahrain-odlay-s3 /var/www/od_serv/public/test -o allow_other`

The command seems to be executing successfully but we are not seeing any result. This was working fine until one morning when we restarted Ec2 and the bucket got unmounted. We ran the script again but we are not longer able to fetch all the subfolders in the bucket

Regards
Syed

Comment: **Site-note:** Amazon S3 is an object storage service, not a network drive. It is not recommended to 'mount' S3 as a drive using utilities such as `s3fs`, especially for production usage. It is preferable to directly interface with Amazon S3, such as using the [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/) or making API calls via an AWS SDK.

Comment: I disagree with the above comment by @JohnRotenstein as it's purely opinion based. The use of s3fuze is up to the OP regardless of whether it's used in dev or production.

Comment: Please move your question to [su] or [sf] (delete here, re-post there). It's [off-topic here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 0):

Without error output details here are some things to check for:

Are the permissions set corrently on the S3 bucket to allow access from your EC2 intance? Ideally this would be set to "no public access" and you are using a specific IAM user to mount the bucket with proper permissions.

When mounting the bucket via "s3fs" be sure and do so with a local Linux user who has read/write access if this is what you desire. I.e. you may create the mount directory via root and then add an /etc/fstab entry as follows:

s3fs#s3-folder-name /mnt/s3bucket fuse _netdev,rw,nosuid,nodev,allow_other,uid=33,gid=33,umask=002,nonempty,passwd_file=/etc/aws/aws-s3-keys 0 0

Where the "/etc/aws/aws-s3-keys" points to a file with your AWS IAM access keys for using S3 service.

I realize this is not a definitive answer but you need to provide more specifics as to your environment for me to help.

Answer (score 0):

I recently did this and faced the same error.
All I did was to put the entry of my bucket, directory and my role into **/etc/fstab.**

**For example:**

s3fs#bucketname  /directoryname  fuse  _netdev,allow_other,nonempty,uid=1002,gid=1002,iam_role=rolename,use_cache=/tmp,url=https://s3.us-east-1.amazonaws.com  0  0

Since then there has been a lot of Stop Starts on this testing server but the S3 Mount Point is always persistent and present.